# How can i make a contraction of this if statement with ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-operator

```
const arr2 = ['', '', '', ''];
```

I made a function using reduce method that returns the number of element when i put a array and a element into the function as arguments . like below.

```
    function count(array, element) {
      return array.reduce((count, value) => {
        if (value === element) {
          count++;
        }
        return count; 
      }, 0);
    }
    result = count(arr2, '');
    console.log(result);
```

***output***

> 2

and it worked well. no problem till here.

but, i wanted to make it shorter using ternary operators.

but it doesn't work.

so i converted it trying my best. like below.

```
    function count(array, element) {
      return array.reduce((count, value) => value === element ? count++ : count, 0);
    }
    result = count(arr2, '');
    console.log(result);
```

***output***

> 0

how can i fix it?

Comment: You're using `++` as post-increment operator. So it first reads and returns the value of `count` and only then increments the value. So `count` will always be `0`. Use `++` as pre-increment operator or just return `count + 1`.

Comment: A better way is to `filter` and return the `length`, like this:  `const count = (array, element) => array.filter(i => i === element).length;`

Comment: @Harrison _"better"_ is subjective. There's nothing wrong (besides the wrong operator) with OPs script.

Comment: @Andreas true, but OP wanted something more akin to a one-liner. They were incrementing a value, which is unnecessary in the way they needed it.